# prove that $\int _{-\infty }^\infty \frac{1}{1+f(x)}\operatorname{dx}$ diverges

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f : \Bbb R \to  [0,\infty )$ be a measurable function. If $\int _{-\infty }^\infty f(x)\operatorname{d}x= 1 $
>   then
>   prove that $\int _{-\infty }^\infty \frac{1}{1+f(x)}\operatorname{d}x= \infty $.

I am absolutely clueless on how to start this except applying the definition of a measurable function.

Any hints on this problem will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f(x)\ge0$, we have $\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}\le f(x)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-n}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(x)}
&=2n-\int_{-n}^n\frac{f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{1+f(x)}\\[6pt]
&\ge2n-1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

Let $I_n = \frac{1}{2n} \int_{-n}^n f(x)\,dx$.  By monotone or dominated convergence, $I_n \to 0$.

By Jensen's inequality, $$\frac{1}{2n} \int_{-n}^n \frac{1}{1+f(x)}\,dx \ge \frac{1}{1 + I_n}.$$
That is,
$$\int_{-n}^n \frac{1}{1+f(x)}\,dx \ge \frac{2n}{1+I_n}.$$
Now let $n \to \infty$.